# Рисунок круга и изгиба для svg

Tags: html, css, svg

```
d: path('M0,0 0,3.5 3.5,1.75z');
```

Это стрелка, как будет выглядеть параметр если необходим простой круг?
Возможно ли его нарисовать для тега

```
<circle cx="18" cy="18" r="15"></circle>
```

И такой плавный изгиб дуги по левому краю (под viewBox="0 0 36 36")

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Искал решение, выполнить плавный изгиб через css. Единственный выход, делать радиус на блок и увеличивать его в 2-3-5 раз, прятать все что за родителя выходит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Форму красной стрелки,  можно реализовать, как средствами CSS так и SVG

### Решение CSS

*С помощью border*

```css
.box {
width:200px;
height:200px;
margin:0.5em;
background: red;
    border-top-left-radius: 1.5em 20em;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 1.5em 20em;
 }
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

`border-top-left-radius: 2em 15em;` ,где
`1.5em` - горизонтальный радиус
`20em` - вертикальный радиус

В помощь прочитайте отличную [статью на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/141658/)

В теге `circle` такого сделать не возможно.
Такую форму можно сделать только с помощью самостоятельного тега `<path>`

### Решение SVG

```css
.container {
width:30vw;
height:30vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 36 36">
  <path id="arrow" d="M34.2 2H6S3.6 13 3.6 18.5C3.6 23.9 6 33.9 6 33.9h28.2Z"  fill="#ED1B24" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
</div>
```

### Update

На исправленной версии видно, что радиусы одинаковые, и  отступы одинаковые. Чёрная рамка,- это граница SVG холста После настройки рамку - `style="border:1px solid"` можно удалить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.container {
width:35vw;
height:35vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 36 36" style="border:1px solid">
  <path id="arrow" d="M34.2 2H3.1S1.8 13 1.8 18.5A185 185 0 0 0 3.1 34h31.1z"  fill="gold" stroke-width="1" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" />
</svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовал, не то. Какая та угловатая дуга получается

Comment: Под viewBox="0 0 36 36", через path пожалуй намного лучше получиться. Плавность и качество

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Немного изменил атрибуты. Сейчас сделаю вариант на SVG

Comment: То, но отступы и радиус получился неровным. Такой вот вопрос, что если в svg добавить блок котому возможно было бы задать ширину и высоту, указать радиус в 50%. Увеличить его в 2 раза и сдвинуть правее. Пожалуй должно быть идеально ровно. Просидел, правил цифры, никак ровно не вышло выполнить

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов Так не получится. Сейчас отступы выровняю и радиус уменьшу. Работай в векторном редакторе, вручную тяжело редактировать цифры на кривых